# Sort objects in List by properties on the object

Tags: c#, list, sorting, properties

I have a List of objects in C#. All the objects contain properties code1 and code2 (among other properties). The list of objects is in no particular order.
I need to sort the list of objects by their code1 and code2 properties.

Example:

```
List -> object = id, name, code1, code2, hours, amount.
```

Example code 1 = 004
Example code 2 = 001, 002, 003, 004, 016
Example code 1 = 005
Example code 2 = 001, 002, 003, 004

So after the sort I would want the objects in the following order

```
004 001
004 002
004 003
004 005
004 016
005 001
005 002
005 003
005 004
```

Comment: +1 Not sure why you were downvoted.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use linq extensions (leaving the original list unsorted):

```
var sorted = theList.OrderBy(o => o.code1).ThenBy(o => o.code2);
```

To replace the original list with a sorted one, make a slight amendment (not very efficient, it creates a new list):

```
theList = theList.OrderBy(o => o.code1).ThenBy(o => o.code2).ToList();
```

This assumes that your list is of the correct type, something like:

```
List<MyClass> theList = new List<MyClass>();
```

And not a list of objects, in which case you would need to make use of `.Cast<>()` or `.OfType<>()`.

Comment: Note that this leaves the original list unsorted.

Comment: The ToList call, as I imagine you are aware, *still* does not sort the original list; it creates a new list with the items in order.  That will most likely be slightly slower than sorting the list in place; it will certainly require more memory, and if the list is large, the extra memory pressure may have a significant impact on performace.

Comment: @phoog Fair enough - I held off providing an implementation of the Sort method as I couldn't be confident of it without compiling and trying it. I've amended my answer to be a little more explicit.

Answer (score 11):

Note that Adam Houldsworth's answer with the `.ToList()` call needlessly creates a new list.  If your list is large, this may create unacceptable memory pressure.  It would most likely be better to sort the list in place by providing a custom comparison function:

```
theList.Sort((a, b) =>
    {
        var firstCompare = a.code1.CompareTo(b.code1);
        return firstCompare != 0 ? firstCompare : a.code2.CompareTo(b.code2);
    });
```

Alternatively, if this ordering is an intrinsic property of your type, you could implement `IComparable<T>` on your type, and just call

```
theList.Sort();
```

... which will use the `IComparable<T>.CompareTo()` implementation.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth And of course your approach gives neater code.  I'd probably use Linq if I were certain that the list would never contain more than a handful of items, since performance would not likely be an issue in that case.