# How to Sort a List by a property in the object

Tags: c#

I have a class called Factor which has properties as Id,Explain,Date,Amount and .... I have a List of this "Factor " class.

Now i want to sort the list based on one property of the Factor object(by date)

```
public class Factor
    {
        public DateTime? date { set; get; }
        public string InnovoiceId { set; get; }
        public string explain { set; get; }
        public Int64? bedehkar { set; get; }
        public Int64? bestankar { set; get; }
        public Int64? mande { set; get; }



     }

        List<Factor> factors=new List<Factor>();
```

How can i do this in C# ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013207/sort-objects-in-list-by-properties-on-the-object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use LINQ to get new list with items sorted:

```
var sortedFactors = factors.OrderBy(x => x.explain).ToList();
```

or you can sort it in-place using [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
factors.Sort((e1, e2) => e1.explain.CompareTo(e2.explain));
```

***Update***

Using `List<T>.Sort` with `date` property is a little bit more tricky, because its `Nullable<DateTime>`, and it's not really obvious how to order `null` and non-`null` values.

```
factors.Sort((e1, e2) => e1.date.HasValue ? (e2.date.HasValue ? e1.date.Value.CompareTo(e2.date.Value) : -1) : ((e2.date.HasValue ? 1 : 0)));
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not "the list" he or she had in the beginning any more like that.

Comment: He wants to order by `date`, +1 anyway ;)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Yes, now. The OP said in his question he or she wants to sort *that* list, so `OrderBy` wasn't exactly the first association.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper There are cases when you need sorted version of list without modifying the source collection.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Which isn't the case here, as the question says "Now i want to sort the list".

Comment: So i need to sort the list by increasing option

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the overloads of the [`Sort` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). A simply one to use is this one that takes a lambda expression for the sorting criterion - essentially a function that takes two elements and returns a comparison result:

```
factors.Sort((x, y) => x.date.CompareTo(y.date));
```

As you are using `DateTime?`, you also need to check whether there is currently a value stored in there.

Comment: Yes i am using DateTime?